# best way to display 55 million product variations of one product?

Tags: magento2, products

I have an external DB that has 55 million unique products. In this case, vehicle license plates. An api returns the results, the only two fields that are significant to the purchase are the price and a seven-digit text field.

I was thinking the best way to handle this would be to set up one product that I can pass these two variables to once a customer has selected his license plate from the results.

Does anybody have any better suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

I think setting up one product and using the customizable options. You could use a custom text field and populate the "digits". As for price you would need to edit the the script that calculates the price on the PDP. If i am understanding you correctly.